# gmaps4rails shows marker just off map when map inside tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmaps4rails

I am using Gmaps4rails and I managed to get it working inside a tab adding this code to the tab funcionality.

```
$(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
                        fx: { opacity: 'toggle' },
                        select: function(event, ui) {
                                jQuery(this).css('height', jQuery(this).height());
                                jQuery(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');
                        },
                        show: function(event, ui) {
                                jQuery(this).css('height', 'auto');
                                jQuery(this).css('overflow', 'visible');
                                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        }

                });
```

http://hik-fyp.heroku.com/en/events/31

As you can see in this example(scroll down and click 'Map' tab) the map looks fine but the marker is just off the top-left corner. The marker is on the right position, the map is not center.

Any idea why is that?

Comment: Could you post the code where you define your map on the Rails side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is only marker of the map:

```
var lat = Gmaps.map.markers[0].lat;
var lng = Gmaps.map.markers[0].lng;
var centerpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
Gmaps.map.map.setCenter(centerpoint);
```

preferably you should be able to give this cords when you are creating marker